# ZipFile. ExtractToDirectory gives System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in mscorlib

Tags: c#-4.0, zip

I have a project in .NET 4.8 and C# 7.3

I'm using System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory to unzip a zip-file.
I have referenced System.IO.Compression.FileSystem Version 4.0.0.0, File Version: 4.8.3761.0

```
string layout = @"c:\foo\bar\layout1.zip";
string directory = @"C:\temp"

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(layout, directory);
```

I get this exception on the above line

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\datetime.cs:line 611
```

**The file is unzipped, so is this an exception that I can ignore?
If not, what's the problem and how do I fix it??**

Comment: Encountering this issue too, but strangely, only while debugging...